# Can the Hebrew use/jargon policy be expanded to include full English translations where possible?

Tags: discussion, hebrew, citing-sources, language

I was looking around to see if this was already covered, but I only found questions/answers related to jargon/individual terms/transliterations.  I have learned an awful lot on this site so far, but I am having a problem trying to understand some answers.  A lot of answers have both Hebrew sources and their English translations linked(perfect!!), but for others, I am psyched to learn the answer, and I run into something like:

"Yes, always. So-and-So explains it clearly and concisely in his book Xxxx section 32 right HERE"

...and the HERE link is from HebrewBooks or another Hebrew site without an English translation option.... if I want the answer I have to root around the Web elsewhere for the translation. I am trying to learn to read and understand the Hebrew texts without vowels, but it's a slow gradual process.  The Hebrew use/jargon policy has good guidelines, but I would love to see it expanded beyond terms and jargon to include full answer sources...or at least convince more answerers to give translation links whenever possible as a standard procedure.  Thank you for everything I've learned so far!!

Comment: Thanks for bringing this up.  Actually, if answers just say "see here (link)" and don't also summarize the contents, they're not very good answers quite aside from any language issues.  We should be striving for complete answers -- which will often still contain links, a good practice, but at that point it's for *support*, not *primary content*.  The primary content, the actual answer to the question, belongs on this site.

Comment: sometimes they do, sometimes they don't(summarize),  ...the source texts usually go way beyond the question's answer, I love it when there's a goldmine of information in the source.. I sometimes find myself a few links beyond on a "new research project"... and it all started with the M Y question!

Comment: (Detagged [meta-tag:feature-request] only because this is a request for Mi Yodeya policy/practice not for software implementation or the like.)

Comment: Note that there aren't online English versions available for every Hebrew source there is.

Comment: I think people should at least translate the Hebrew they write into comments... especially if it is a phrase or in fact the whole comment.

Comment: I would like to think that the language for this site is English. If you give a source it would be good to translate the section of it to which are you quoting.

In general I do see the answers in English just that the source they show can be in Hebrew and unless you can translate it yourself you can't verify its validity.